# Problem with fonts on Kubuntu 14.04 and FF29

Tags: 14.04, firefox, kubuntu, kde

yesterday I updated my machine to Kubuntu 14.04 and Firefox to version 29. Now, I have an issue with some fonts, specially on rendering inputs. The font is noticeable bolder and bigger than before, and also, bolder and bigger than on Opera on the same machine. Below you can see an example of a webpage opened on FF 29 and Opera 12.16 on my computer.

This used to work before updating to 14.04. I mean, they looked exactly the same. So I think something broke on the font size of things. Any idea?

Before someone forgets. No Addons running on FF, no zoom either. There are also no vendor specific settings here. I opened it on a friends computer running FF29 under Gnome (Arch Linux fully updated) and it worked like it should, so the problem is on FF on KDE.

For the page, the `font-family: Helvetica,arial,sans-serif`, the font settings on KDE can be seen on the last image. As I said, only thing that changed was doing the Full release upgrade. Any ideas?

[image: Firefox 29]

[image: Opera]

[image: Font Configuration]

Comment: Can you open Font Manager and see which fonts are available (in the order listed for `font-family`)? I'm guessing Helvetica and Arial aren't available.

Comment: @saiarcot895 indeed no Helvetica or Arial available. You think the update removed them? (I don't remember if I had them before). If not, is it possible that Ubuntu changed the default sans-serif font?

Comment: No, Helvetica isn't available directly from Ubuntu because it's a closed-source/proprietary (whichever the appropriate term is) font. You would have to manually install it from the Internet. I'm not sure what would cause significant rendering differences (in terms of fonts) between two browsers on the same computer.

Comment: Yeah, and more importantly, why an Update on the system would cause it. Because it was working before upgrading to 14.04\FF29. So something when I did that upgrade changed, and I don't know what could it be.